# T-SQL SUM All with a Conditional COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that produces the following:

```
Team  | Member  |  Cancelled | Rate
-----------------------------------
  1     John         FALSE      150
  1     Bill         TRUE        10
  2     Sarah        FALSE      145
  2     James        FALSE      110
  2     Ashley       TRUE         0
```

What I need is to select the count of members for a team where cancelled is false and the sum of the rate regardless of cancelled status...something like this:

```
SELECT
    Team,
    COUNT(Member),    --WHERE Cancelled = FALSE
    SUM(Rate)         --All Rows
FROM
    [QUERY]
GROUP BY
    Team
```

So the result would look like this:

```
Team  |  CountOfMember | SumOfRate
----------------------------------
  1           1                160
  2           2                255
```

This is just an example.  The real query has multiple complex joins.  I know I could do one query for the sum of the rate and then another for the count and then join the results of those two together, but is there a simpler way that would be less taxing and not cause me to copy and paste an already complex query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want a conditional sum, something like this:

```
sum(case when cancelled = 'false' then 1 else 0 end)
```

The reason for using `sum()`.  The `sum()` is processing the records and adding a value, either `0` or `1` for every record.  The value depends on the valued of `cancelled`.  When it is false, then the `sum()` increments by `1` -- counting the number of such values.

You can do something similar with `count()`, like this:

```
count(case when cancelled = 'false' then cancelled end)
```

The trick here is that `count()` counts the number of non-NULL values.  The `then` clause can be anything that is not NULL -- `cancelled`, the constant `1`, or some other field.  Without an else, any other value is turned into `NULL` and not counted.

I have always preferred the `sum()` version over the `count()` version, because I think it is more explicit.  In other dialects of SQL, you can sometimes shorten it to:

```
sum(cancelled = 'false')
```

which, once you get used to it, makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Using SUM instead of COUNT.  That's genius!

Comment: @GordonLinoff: It might be worth mentioning why we need `SUM` instead of `COUNT` here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You don't absolutely need `Sum`: `Count(CASE WHEN Cancelled = 'false' THEN 1 END)` works as well, although I agree `Sum` is better form. Lately, I have toyed with `Count((SELECT 1 WHERE Cancelled = 'false'))`, though it also is perhaps not best form.