# Return tag string based on two conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a `Tags` column, which contains items like so: `'server, network, location1'`...

I need to find all records where the item '`storage`' is present
AND
where any of these locations are present `('location1', location2, location3')`
AND 
where no other items are present (i.e. only '`storage`' and a `location` OR only '`storage`').

I'm using a function to split the string into items, so a select statement for the code below using Tags for the entire string and Item for the items will help me a lot.

```
SELECT cardid, item, tags, count(1) as Total
, result = 
    case when lower(item) = 'storage' and
    lower(item) in 'location1, location2, location3' 
    then 'yes'
    else 'no'
    end
FROM myTable 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_SplitString(Tags, ',')
GROUP BY cardid, item, tags 
order by item desc
```

Here is the function I use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString]   
(   
    @String VARCHAR(8000),   
    @Delimiter VARCHAR(255)   
)   
RETURNS   
@Results TABLE   
(   
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),   
    Item VARCHAR(8000)   
)   
AS   
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO @Results (Item)   
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String+@Delimiter, Number,   
    CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String+@Delimiter, Number) - Number)   
FROM Numbers   
WHERE Number <= LEN(REPLACE(@String,' ','|'))   
AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @String,   
            Number,   
            LEN(REPLACE(@delimiter,' ','|'))) = @Delimiter   
ORDER BY Number RETURN   
END
```

Comment: could you please add some sample expected output and also clarify more on what is your ask

Comment: Yes, apologies for being unclear. Output would be all rows with the string 'storage' either as only content or with one of the location strings, for example: 'storage' or 'storage, location1' or 'location2, storage'. I need to filter out all rows with the string 'storage' and some other text than any of the locations.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL statements, sample data as DML statements and desired results.

Comment: No DDL. DML is above (I think). Desired results are explained twice, in the question and in a comment above. I simply need help from someone who can figure out how to only return records where a specific word and/or a location is included in a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"to find all records where ..." your query should be changed to this:

```
SELECT MT.cardid, MT.tags, count(1) as Total
FROM myTable AS MT
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_SplitString(Tags, ',') AS TagList
GROUP BY MT.cardid, MT.tags
HAVING COUNT( * ) =
        COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Item IN( 'location1', 'location2', 'location3' ) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )
        + COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Item = 'storage' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )
    AND COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Item = 'storage' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) >= 1
ORDER BY MT.cardid DESC
```

The above query is using "Conditional Aggregation". I have added `HAVING` clause where for each group `COUNT` of all tags is compared to the sum of "location" tags `COUNT` and "storage" tag `COUNT`. The next condition checks that the `COUNT` of "storage" is greater or equal to 1 (if you need only 1 storage element than change it to `= 1`)
**Note:** I made an assumption that your dbo.fn_SplitString function returns a table with a column called "Item".
**Note 2:** notice that I have given an alias ("AS TagList") to the function.

If you want the query to return all rows and simply indicate if a row matches your tag condition (like the example query you have given) then move all `HAVING` conditions to your `CASE` statement and remove `HAVING`

```
SELECT MT.cardid, MT.tags, COUNT(*) as Total
, result = 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT( * ) =
                COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Value IN( 'location1', 'location2', 'location3' ) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )
                + COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Value = 'storage' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )
            AND COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Item = 'storage' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) >= 1
    THEN 'yes'
    ELSE 'no'
    END
FROM myTable AS MT
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_SplitString(Tags, ',') AS TagList
GROUP BY MT.cardid, MT.tags
ORDER BY MT.cardid DESC
```

Below is a working example:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE( GroupID INT, Tag VARCHAR( 20 ))
INSERT INTO @Sample( GroupID, Tag )
VALUES
( 1, 'location1' ),( 1, 'location2' ), ( 1, 'storage' ),
( 2, 'location1' ),( 2, 'location2' ), ( 2, 'something else' ),
( 3, 'storage' )

SELECT GroupID
FROM @Sample AS TagList
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING COUNT( * ) =
        COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Tag IN( 'location1', 'location2', 'location3' ) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )
        + COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Tag = 'storage' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END )
    AND COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Tag = 'storage' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) >= 1
```

In the future please provide a sample table like the one above.

**Update** (to answer your comments):
Notice that the function below is a table valued function which returns a table with one column: `@Results TABLE( Value VARCHAR( MAX ))`. The name of the column is "Value" (in your case it may be a different name). So in your query to access data returned by this function you specify the name of this column (in my case it is "Value").

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_SplitString
(
    @Source VARCHAR( MAX ),
    @Delimiter VARCHAR( 100 )
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE( Value VARCHAR( MAX ))
AS
BEGIN
    -- The main body of code has been excluded for brevity
END
```

Links to similar questions that contain explanations:
[T-SQL SUM All with a Conditional COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180590/t-sql-sum-all-with-a-conditional-count)
[Create a view with totals from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198598/sql-server-create-a-view-with-totals-from-multiple-columns/37289412#37289412)
[SQL Server - conditional aggregation with correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481732/sql-server-conditional-aggregation-with-correlation)

Comment: Wow - much appreciated, Alex! I'll remember the sample table. Now how do I accept your answer, give you points, close the question or something...?

Comment: There is large "tick symbol" just below the answer (my answer) score. This will accept the answer.

Comment: I only get the correct results in the last query - the working example. The other two return records with other words than location and storage. Am I doing something wrong? I replaced 'Value' with 'item' as I have no 'Value' in the string function, but the tag string is divided into several 'items' (each word). I see the tick - thanks :).

Comment: @preston, see **Update** at the bottom of my answer. Basically you need to find out the name of the column returned by your function and use that column

Comment: Thanks Alex. In my case the column name is 'item' and I seem to get wrong results when I use that. I will try some different things and post back - it's probably a mistake on my end! I just posted the split string function in the question.

Comment: In your working example, aren't tags divided into separate words? In my origin table the tags are several words with ',' delimiter. Such as: 'server, storage, location1'. Or: 'location1, storage' - where only the latter is to be returned.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. Item column comes from the fn_SplitString (I initially thought it was coming from myTable). You need to remove Item column from the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`. I have updated my answer. I hope you can see why sample tables and a list of expected results have to be provided with the question (especially, as in your case, when requirements are non-trivial).

Comment: Yes, apologies for not being clear, Alex. I'm not used to posting questions - I'll learn quickly. It's almost there - but I still get records with only location, where I should only return records with storage alone - or storage and location. I used the updated code with MyTable as MT.

Comment: Answer updated. I have added "AND COUNT( CASE WHEN TagList.Item = 'storage' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) >= 1" . I think you should start getting the gist of the idea behind the solution.

Comment: It works! I am definitely getting the gist. Thanks a billion, mate. The help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome and an upvote for the effort would be welcome as well ;)

Comment: I clicked the upvote, but my reputation is too low for it to show :D.